# Vim yank/copy all multi-line patterns in file

Tags: regex, vim, multiline

I have a large file where I want to copy only portions of the file that match a regex (multiline) pattern. I found somewhere (probably StackOverflow) that I can do this:

```
:g/z=45117\.1[0-9]\{2}nm\_.\{-}end/y
```

This pattern found all the entries I was expecting, but the yank operation only yanked the first line of the first match found

**What vim magic do I need to yank all lines of all matches of the multi-line pattern?**

Answer (score 6):

Add an `A` with a space to the end of the command:

```
:g/z=45117\.1[0-9]\{2}nm\_.\{-}end/y A
```

It yanks the pattern into register `a`, so you might want to clear it before the command:

```
:let @a = ''
```

Comment: Faster register clear: `qaq` (record macro to `@a` and immediately stop).

Comment: This didn't work as I had hoped. When I pasted (using `"Ap`) it still just pasted the first line instead of the multiline string.